# How to apply numpy functions on a slice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(100, 30, 3)`. I wanted to apply a function to transform the second dimension (`N=30`) based on the slice from third dimension.

For example, consider I am doing a machine learning and my shape is `(Samples, 1D Pixels, Color Channels)`. Now I want to apply `np.log` on the 2nd color channel. Something like `np.log(x, axis=1, slice_axis=2, slice_index=1)` to apply log on `(:,:,1)`. How?

Comment: Does this not work: `np.log(x[:, :, 1])` ? Can you clarify what's the expected output with a concrete example?

Comment: It does. But it changes my shape to `(100,30)`.

Comment: Do you want the operation in place? If that's so, you can do `np.log(x[:, :, 1], out=x[:, :, 1])`.

Comment: `arr[:,:,1] = np.log(arr[:,:,1])` should do it (provided `arr` is a float dtype.

Comment: Thanks @AbhinavGoyal. I didnt know there is out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For applying operations like `np.log` in-place, you can use the `out` parameter. For the problem you mentioned, `np.log(x[:, : ,1], out=x[:, : ,1])`.